# Can I append to a numpy array based on the content of 2 column?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, append

```
array = np.array(
        [[  1.,    1.,   82. , 177.,    0.,    0.,   -1. ],
         [  2.,    2.,   83. , 177.,    0.,    0.,    1. ],
         [  3.,    2.,   84. , 177.,    0.,    0.,    2. ],
         [  4.,    2.,   85. , 177.,    0.,    0.,    2. ],
         [  5.,    2.,   82.5, 177.,    0.,    0.,    2. ],
         [  6.,    2.,   83.5, 177.,    0.,    0.,    3. ]])
```

then I have list of new elements to append which are:

```
new_points = np.array(
   [[  7.,    2.,   82.5, 177.,    0.,    0.,    2. ],
    [  8.,    2.,   83.5, 177.,    0.,    0.,    4. ],
    [  9.,    2.,   84.5, 177.,    0.,    0.,    4. ],
    [ 10.,    2.,   84. , 177.,    0.,    0.,    4. ]])
```

as you can see some rows have the same values in the 3rd and 4th columns that are also present in the array.
So, I want to append only the point which combination of values in the 3rd and 4th columns are not present in the original array.

the output that I expect is:

```
 array = [[  1.    1.   82.  177.    0.    0.   -1. ]
             [  2.    2.   83.  177.    0.    0.    1. ]
             [  3.    2.   84.  177.    0.    0.    2. ]
             [  4.    2.   85.  177.    0.    0.    2. ]
             [  5.    2.   82.5 177.    0.    0.    2. ]
             [  6.    2.   83.5 177.    0.    0.    3. ]
             [  9.    2.   84.5 177.    0.    0.    4. ]]
```

Comment: you can do this without using any for loops and leveraging the broadcasting capabilities of numpy to get a purely vectorized code. check my solution for that method.

Answer (score 1):

### A pure `numpy` vectorized solution

This an interesting problem that truly shows how powerful `numpy` can be if you understand broadcasting. Avoid using any for loops for this.

You can do this in a **completely vectorized** way using **broadcasting to compare duplicates** in the specific columns (3rd, 4th) and then fetching those rows, **reducing the dimensions** to a boolean array for the new points, and **stacking** them with original as below. For more details read the `NumPy` documentation on [how broadcasting works](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html).

```
cond = ~(array[:,None,2:4] == new_points[None,:,2:4]).all(-1).any(0)
updated_array = np.vstack([array,new_points[cond]])
updated_array
```

```
array([[  1. ,   1. ,  82. , 177. ,   0. ,   0. ,  -1. ],
       [  2. ,   2. ,  83. , 177. ,   0. ,   0. ,   1. ],
       [  3. ,   2. ,  84. , 177. ,   0. ,   0. ,   2. ],
       [  4. ,   2. ,  85. , 177. ,   0. ,   0. ,   2. ],
       [  5. ,   2. ,  82.5, 177. ,   0. ,   0. ,   2. ],
       [  6. ,   2. ,  83.5, 177. ,   0. ,   0. ,   3. ],
       [  9. ,   2. ,  84.5, 177. ,   0. ,   0. ,   4. ]])
```

### EXPLANATION

Here is the flow of shapes for each step -

```
#Broadcasting rules

(6, 1, 2) # array[:,None,2:4]
(1, 4, 2) # new_points[None,:,2:4]
---------
(6, 4, 2) # == compare with broadcasting
---------
(6, 4)    # .all(-1)
(4,)      # .any(0)
(4,)      # ~ invert boolean
```

1. `array[:,None,2:4]` and `new_points[None,:,2:4]` fetches the 3rd and 4th column but also adds a dummy dimension in the arrays. This makes their shape as `(6, 1, 2)` and `(1, 4, 2)` respectively. Why is this important?
2. Because this allows us to use broadcasting to compare the 6 rows to the 4 rows. This is done with just the `==` step. This step `array[:,None,2:4] == new_points[None,:,2:4]` basically results in a `(6, 4, 2)` boolean matrix that compares every value from the 3rd and 4th column respectively across the 6 and 4 rows.
3. Since you want to match both values exactly, you can use `.all(-1)` which reduces the last dimension giving you are `(6,4)` matrix with True and False values. (True means both values match, False means both values don't match)

```
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False],
       [ True, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False]])
```

4. Finally, since I want to filter only the rows that are duplicate in the original matrix (based on 3rd and 4th column) I can reduce the first axis (0) to get a `(4,)` boolean array, using `.any(0)`

```
array([ True,  True, False,  True])
```

5. Oh, and we want to finally also switch the False to True and vice versa, since True means keep and False means drop in boolean indexing. This is done with the `~` at the start.

```
array([False, False,  True, False]) #this is the cond variable
```

6. Last step would be to filter the `new_points` array and stack it to the `array`, using `np.vstack`

---

#### Benchmarks -

Just to show the power of vectorization, here are some benchmarks from other answers -

```
#Vectorized solution

%%timeit

cond = ~(array[:,None,2:4] == new_points[None,:,2:4]).all(-1).any(0)
updated_array = np.vstack([array,new_points[cond]])

# 9.77 µs ± 145 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

```
# For loop solution

%%timeit

filtered_points = []
for point in new_points:
    if not np.any((array[:,2] == point[2]) & (array[:,3] == point[3])):
        filtered_points.append(point)
result = np.concatenate((array, filtered_points))

#28.8 µs ± 651 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach as well to achieve that goal:

```py
import numpy as np

array = np.array(
        [[  1.,    1.,   82. , 177.,    0.,    0.,   -1. ],
         [  2.,    2.,   83. , 177.,    0.,    0.,    1. ],
         [  3.,    2.,   84. , 177.,    0.,    0.,    2. ],
         [  4.,    2.,   85. , 177.,    0.,    0.,    2. ],
         [  5.,    2.,   82.5, 177.,    0.,    0.,    2. ],
         [  6.,    2.,   83.5, 177.,    0.,    0.,    3. ]])

new_points = np.array(
   [[  7.,    2.,   82.5, 177.,    0.,    0.,    2. ],
    [  8.,    2.,   83.5, 177.,    0.,    0.,    4. ],
    [  9.,    2.,   84.5, 177.,    0.,    0.,    4. ],
    [ 10.,    2.,   84. , 177.,    0.,    0.,    4. ]])

filtered_points = []
for point in new_points:
    if not np.any((array[:,2] == point[2]) & (array[:,3] == point[3])):
        filtered_points.append(point)
result = np.concatenate((array, filtered_points))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[  1.    1.   82.  177.    0.    0.   -1. ]
 [  2.    2.   83.  177.    0.    0.    1. ]
 [  3.    2.   84.  177.    0.    0.    2. ]
 [  4.    2.   85.  177.    0.    0.    2. ]
 [  5.    2.   82.5 177.    0.    0.    2. ]
 [  6.    2.   83.5 177.    0.    0.    3. ]
 [  9.    2.   84.5 177.    0.    0.    4. ]]
```

**Explanation:**
**1.** Create an empty list called `filtered_points`.

**2.** Iterate over the elements in `new_points`. For each element, check if the combination of values in the `3rd` and `4th` columns is present in the array. If it is not present, append the element to `filtered_points`.

**3.** Use the `np.concatenate` function to concatenate array and `filtered_points` and assign the result to a new variable called `result`.

The resulting `result` array will contain only the elements from `new_points` that have a combination of values in the `3rd` and `4th` columns that are not present in array.

Comment: In general, a solution that iterates over a numpy solution will be slower than one that uses numpy's vectorization magic and delegate the iterations to the numpy backend. One good thing about your solution is you append all filtered points at once, instead of one-by-one, thereby requiring only one copy of the old numpy array instead of `len(filtered_points)`